# Unique Items in Array using jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Have an issue (not overly complicated, however I just can't seem to think of a clear way to solve).

I have an array of items, in which there is a recurring id, so for illustrative purposes think:

```
[
    {name: "john", task: "dig"},
    {name: "john", task: "swim"},
    {name: "john", task: "eat"},
    {name: "paul", task: "dig"},
]
```

From this I want to create a table where the columns would be the name - so John and Paul, then underneath there would be the tasks.

I'm thinking I'd need 2 for loops however not sure how the first would just get the 'unique' names.

Is there something in jQuery i can use that can solve.

Comment: reduce would do the trick I guess... no loops needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var arr = 
[
    {name: 'john', task: 'dig'},
    {name: 'john', task: 'swim'},
    {name: 'john', task: 'eat'},
    {name: 'paul', task: 'dig'},
];
var result = arr.reduce(function(table, element)
{
    if(!table[element.name])
    {
        table[element.name] = [];
    }
    table[element.name].push(element.task);
    return table;
}, {});
// For demo:
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Perfect - love how there's so many great functions available :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of underscore library _.unique function.

First we need to convert the arrary from array of objects, to array of strings, by using JavaScript map function.

After that, we using _.unique to get only unique strings.

```
x=[
{name: 'john', task: 'dig'},
{name: 'dani', task: 'didg'},
{name: 'john', task: 'diadg'},
{name: 'john', task: 'diasdg'},
];
x=x.map(function (i) {return i.name}) // ['john','dani','john','john']
x=_.unique(x)     //   ['john','dani']
```

http://underscorejs.org/#uniq (_.uniq and _.unique are the same)

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `$.each()`

```js
var data = [{
  name: "john",
  task: "dig"
}, {
  name: "john",
  task: "swim"
}, {
  name: "john",
  task: "eat"
}, {
  name: "paul",
  task: "dig"
}];

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  var fn = function(el) {
    return el.find("tbody").append($("<tr />", {
      "html": "<td>" + value.task + "</td>"
    }))
  }
  if (!$("table[name=" + value.name + "]").is("*")) {
    var elem = $("<table />", {
      "name": value.name,
      "html": "<tbody><th>" + value.name + "</th></tbody>"
    }).appendTo("body");
    fn(elem)
  } else {
    fn($("table[name=" + value.name + "]"))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```